# How do we properly set LoadFactor & concurrency level of our concurrenthashmap?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Am trying to use a concurrent hashmap as a cache for my application, so that it will load all the data from the database at the start.My question is how do I determine the best base configuration of the properties of my concurrent hash map.How do I determine best load factor and concurrency level for my CHM? And this is confusing me because, since we don't know how many threads will try to access my CHM( It all depends on the currently logged in users).

ConcurrentHashMap m = new ConcurrentHashMap(200 , ??, ??);

Concurrent requests could be 100,000 or 1M or 5M, it all depends on logged in users?

Comment: Honestly, don't bother.  Accept the defaults, it's not likely to make a difference.  (I believe in the Java 8 HashMap, the concurrency level is actually ignored.)

Comment: Which version of Java you are using? And once loaded will it get modified? And to note even though requests will be 1M or 5M no of threads will be less. Check your web server regarding no of threads it creates.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: almost. Starting with Java 8, the concurrency level will be used as hint for the initial size, but nothing more…

Comment: 1.Because the project that is working on right now is old, we are using Java 7.

Comment: 1.Because the project that is working on right now is old, we are using Java 7.    2.Once loaded, yes when every the database gets modified, our CHM will be modified. 3. & yes you're right the number of threads will be less, but Since they only need for the threads for the modification operation only(we don't need any lock for reading), I do I determine it.  4. what about the load factor, how do we determine the best load factor.

Answer (score 0):

First, what you are doing is made complicated by the fact that you must load the values from a database. This assumes that a database connection is available before you start this process.

Second, do you intend to modify the values in the cache once they are loaded? Concurrency still adds some overhead, even if it is less than using synchronize.

If not, look at using some sort of immutable Map, such as ImmutableMap implemented by Google. Load your map in the class static initializer. This method must complete before any access to the Map is allowed. Therefore, you don't have any concurrency issues.

Comment: Thank you, Steve, yes you are right. Secondly, yes they are going to be modified whenever there is a change. The main problem is that the whole project is old and we are unable to use cache frameworks. But the main thing that i want you to help me, Steve, is that, let's just say we have to use CHM to hold large data that will be accessed concurrently.  how would you approach it to determine the needed load factor and Concurrency level? please, if you can give me detailed help(step by step). thank you steve